# Do electronic items age and do they get inefficient as a result?

Tags: cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the performance of a CPU affected as it ages?](https://superuser.com/questions/456445/is-the-performance-of-a-cpu-affected-as-it-ages)

Is there a thing called 'aging' for electronic items? I mean for example, can my processor (CPU) gets inefficient with time or should it be working as the same efficiency that I bought brand new? What is the reason for this?

Comment: Depends on "type" of "electronics": semiconductor (in plastic or ceramic carrier), film caps, electrolytic caps, carbon comp resistors, film resistors, vacuum tubes?

Comment: A CPU, as I read somewhere, has a life of ~10 years..

Answer (score 0):

Entropy, mostly. Everything deteriorates... to some extent. The hotter they run, the faster a CPU will burn out, though I couldn't tell you how long that would take.